# Cron wget commands not reaching website

Tags: php, cron, expressionengine

To cut down on a very long story, we had our own server environment at one point for a client project but it was ultimately decided to go with a third party hosting solution (Nexcess). Prior to this, we had a virtual server utilizing webmin as an interface and it ran on Ubuntu.

The idea was to have some templates within ExpressionEngine which would contain functions that would be triggered every so often per hour. Naturally, this was where Cron came into play. These worked flawlessly for many weeks.

During the migration, Nexcess promised to port everything over (it was part of their appeal to both my company and the client. No additional work for either of us, in theory).

These functions are now no longer firing.

The originals were lost and are now replaced with these (which I did not make, it was most likely Nexcess). They're not reaching the templates, and I know this because I can look at the hit counter. Further, manually firing each template delivers the desired result- so the code itself is fine.

The Cron commands are:

```
wget --user=cron --password='abc123'
-O - -t 5 https://example.com/site/shipping_process

wget --user=cron --password='abc123'
-O - -t 5 https://example.com/site/import


wget --user=cron --password='abc123'
-O - -t 5 https://example.com/site/stockupdate
```

*Note that these templates are protected, and so a user name and password must be given for direct access.

Any clue as to what the hold up is?

On webmin I could actually run tests with Cron and see the output- no such luck with Nexcess and 'Siteworx' (insofar as I am presently able to divine).

So the issue appears to be the host provider is using an outdated version of Wget. This older version has particular problems with SSL which are applicable in our case. They are suggesting we rebuild the statements using Curl.

What might the equivalents be for what we have above (I'm researching this actively as I ask this).

Put together the following so far, no luck:

```
/usr/bin/curl -username cron:abc123 --silent https:example.com/site/stockupdate &>/dev/null
```

Comment: do the commands work if called from the command line?

Comment: Actually no! I tried that and it spat up errors.. Figured it out though. Unlike in Webmin, apparently I must specify the path to wget.

Still, even after doing that nothing works.

Comment: When you say "nothing works" do you mean that the command does not work from the command line either?  Have you tried it over http instead of https?  Have you tried it on a version without the password requirement?

Comment: Using it over http works. We're not sure why, because we do have a valid SSL cert. 

We're speaking with the host provider- their initial response after looking at everything was "this shouldn't be happening".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

/usr/bin/curl –silent –output -u user:password https://example.com/site/shipping_process

Comment: Did you get an explanation of why this was necessary? Expanding on your answer would help others in the same situation (and get you move upvotes!)